# How to configure .htaccess when a rails application is located inside of another rails' public folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, .htaccess, fastcgi

I have a rails application running on my shared host server and the `public_html` is mapped to `~/rails_apps/app1/public`.
This was done so `www.mydomain.com` launches app1. As expected, the .htaccess is like this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi [QSA,L]
```

Here comes a new rails app2, and I want to access it through `www.mydomain.com/app2`

I created `~/rails_apps/app2`, and created the symlink `public_html/app2` pointing there (the symlink is actually `~/rails_apps/app1/public/app2`).

This app2 also needs the dispatch.fcgi to launch, so the `app2/public/.htaccess` has the same RewriteRules as above.

The problem is that when I access `www.mydomain.com/app2/hello`, my first app1 is receiving the request and it's failing. I'm reading this rule as "File /app2/hello doesn't exist, send it to dispatch.fcgi for processing".

So, I tried setting up an additional rule in app1/public

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/app2/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app2/dispatch.fcgi [L]
```

My app2 is now getting the request, but it tries to process `/app2/hello` which fails since there is no `/app2` defined in my routes. It needs to receive just `/hello`.

I also tried putting `RewriteBase /app2` just before the rules in the above paragraph, but it didn't seem to make any difference. I also needed to put `RewriteBase /` before the original app1 RewriteRule, otherwise app1 breaks. (sincerely, I don't know if more than one RewriteBase is allowed)

Any ideas how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to adjust the /app2 routes subdirectory try to add

```
config.action_controller.relative_url_root = '/app2'
```

to your environmet.rb (production) ...

hope this could help